# Math.Round doesn't behave like i want it to. (X.0xxxxx numbers)

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding

Quick question.
I'm making a diagram so the numbers i'm passing to the function can be anything (depending on zoom and such). Lets say I want to round the number 3.086948353 to 3 but i still want other numbers like 2.199999999 to round to 2.2.

Currently it just looks like this:

```
Math.Round(value, 10)
```

Comment: So are you asking for a rounding function with a special case for 3.086948353? In what way is 2.199999999 different from 3.086948353? Your ill-specified question seems impossible to answer correctly.

Comment: Quick answer: `If(number == 3.086948353) 3; else Math.Round(number, 2);` otherwise be a little bit more specific and show us what you've tried.

Comment: Show what you've tried and ask a more specific question. What you're asking is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for a poorly formed question. I want to know if there are any flags i can send with the function so that extremely small differences (eg 3.01) will be recognized as a 3. Same goes for 3.00000001.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do two things in single shot:

1. Get the integer value if first digit after decimal is 0
2. Get the rounded value upto last 2 digits if its first digit after decimal is not 0.

For second option you can use:

```
newValue  = Math.Round(value, 2)
```

Now comes the first requirement:
Once you get the decimal with 2 digits after decimal, get last two digits:

```
int decimalValue= (int)((newValue  - (int)newValue ) * 100);
if(decimalValue < 10)
{
  newValue = Math.Floor(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's basically what i searched for.